# I can only access my school network using Firefox on Lion. How can I fix this so all programs can access the internet?

Tags: wireless-networking, internet, osx-lion

Since upgrading to Lion, only Firefox on my MacBook Pro has been able to connect to the school network. All other programs cannot access the network. However, this problem is remedied by shutting down the computer and restarting it at school. However, I would like to be able to just sleep my computer at home, wake it at school and have all programs work. Any suggestions?

EDIT: If there are any tests I can run on my school network to provide more information, I would be glad post the results.

There are no proxy settings that I know of because when I restart my computer I don't have to enter anything in. However, there is a Microsoft Forefront Login that is required. Again only Firefox can log into this.

Comment: Does your school network require proxy settings?

Comment: Proxy settings can survive across a reboot.  In Firefox, try: Edit > Preferences > Advanced > Network tab > Connection > Settings... (that's where it is on Ubuntu; it might vary slightly in the Mac version).